# Adding an entry to a local DNS server

Tags: networking, dns, dsl-modem

I can access my DSL modem's interface by visiting my public IP address. When I click on DNS Server, I am able to add entries (i.e. mappings from domain name to IP address). I added the domain name in the last entry of the image below to point to Bing's IP address ([204.79.197.200](http://bing.com)).

[image]

However, the domain name still takes me to its original location. *Note that I've included "www"*.

[image: joelchristophel.com]

I've rebooted the modem but get the same result. I've checked my computer's DNS cache to make sure there is not an entry for the domain name there. Why is this not working? Also, why is westell.com there? What's that for? I thought this was a local DNS server.

Comment: If you set the domain name to point to an internal IP address (say 192.168.1.1) does it direct you to there properly? If you do an NSLookup form your computer, does it return the right result?  Are the DNS settings on your computer set to use the router as its DNS server?  Can you post the result of an NSLookup to that domain name for us?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have configured your PC to use your router as the principal DNS server, and for the looks of that page, I think your router would only respond to DNS queries corresponding to subdomains of "westel.com".

Try to reach www.joelchristophel.com.westel.com to check if that redirects you to Bing

If that works, change the domain name to "joelchristophel.com" and add a "www" entry to the Bing IP